# CrossConnectivity.Current.IsRemoteReachable не соединяется

Tags: android, c#, visual-studio-2015, xamarin

Доброе время суток. Есть кроссплатформенное решение Xamarin, установлен плагин Xam.Plugin.Connectivity. В проекте есть проверка на подключение к интернету и попытка соединиться с удалённым сервером. Так вот попытка всегда проваливается, будь то эмулятор или реальный девайс.

Сначала идёт проверка на подключение:
    `CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected`
Возвращает`true`.
Далее, проверяем подключение к удалённому серверу:

```
    private static async Task<bool> ServerAvailable(string URL) {
        var server_available = await CrossConnectivity.Current.IsRemoteReachable(URL);
        return server_available;
    }
```

`CrossConnectivity.Current.IsRemoteReachable` всегда не может соединиться с пунктом назначения. В URL я передаю, например, http://yandex.ru или yandex.ru. Причём если запрос сделать не асинхронным и ждать выполнения, то на данном этапе приложение и застревает с концами.
Вывод `CrossConnectivity.Current.ConnectionTypes` показывает только одно соединение - **Cellular**.

**Android manifest** выглядит вот так:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.companyname.MobileApp" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:label="MobileApp.Android"></application>
</manifest>
```

Проверял на: Android эмулятор 4.4 - 6.0, Android реальный девайс 5.1, Windows Phone эмулятор. Ситуация одинаковая.

Весь Интернет перерыл, все решения найденные поперепробовал, народ просто подключается и у них всё работает.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как решить проблему, в какую сторону копать?

**IDE:** MS Visual Studio Community 2015 v.14.0

**UPD:** **Решил вопрос**. Xam.Plugin.Connectivity работает корректно и проверяющий соединение код тоже верный, не верным было применение этого кода, а именно вся проблема крылась в том, что я новичок в Xamarin и это порождало сразу 2 взаимоисключающие ситуации:
**1.** Запуск асинхронного метода из конструктора (там, где прописывается InitializeComponent();) без ожидания выполнения, таким образом всегда получалось, что connection=false;
**2.** Запуск асинхронного метода из конструктора (там, где прописывается InitializeComponent();) с ожиданием выполнения (Wait(), а сам конструктор конечно же не async), и таким образом получался дэдлок, о чём я и писал изначально.

**Решение:** Ожидать выполнения асинхронного метода (await), но ожидать можно только в соответствующих асинхронных методах (async). Конструктор приложения или страницы сделать асинхронным нельзя, но зато можно сделать таковыми специальные методы OnStart() - задействуется при запуске приложения и OnAppearing() - запускается при открытии страницы соответственно через override. Исходя из вышеизложенного, получаем следующий рабочий код:

*Реализуем проверку в отдельном классе.*

```
public static class Connection
{
    public static async Task<bool> IsAvailable()
    {
        if (CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected)
        {
            var IsConnectionEnabled = await CrossConnectivity.Current.IsRemoteReachable("http://google.com");

            if (IsConnectionEnabled)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

*Применяем статический метод на нужной странице или при запуске приложения.*

```
protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        bool IsConnectionEnabled = await Connection.IsAvailable();

        if (IsConnectionEnabled)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Connection Status", "Connection is OK", "OK");
        }
        else
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Connection Status", "Connection is BAD", "OK"); ;
        }
    }
```

Comment: "Cellular" так как эмулятор дает соединение типа "сотовая связь", качество которой даже можно настраивать. Код и вправду ничего уникального не делает и не зависит на эмуляторе от текущих разрешений в манифесте. Пробовали на пустом проекте? Только стандартные плагины + Xam.Plugin.Connectivity

Comment: Спасибо за интерес к вопросу! Пробовал с десяток новых проектов с минимальным набором необходимого, но проблема крылась в моём нубстве), решение изложил в своём посте.